# howto create login page node.js with session

Tags: javascript

I just heard about node.js and I did a few very begging examples, Now I want to create a login page a long with session functionality. for the time being I would prefer having a constant Username and password in within my code as
var un ="admin";
password="123456";

please help me, I am very new thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Expressjs](http://expressjs.com) as a framework for building your web servers. In the "examples" folder of the [GitHub Repo](http://github.com/visionmedia/express) it shows an example of how to include session support and authorization.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however, I would like to use core node.js not any framework such as Express. I want to learn first the node.js then will move to framework. I saw some session mobules. However, could not get a beginner example

Comment: Understandable. Thats a mighty tall order as the reason Express exists is there is a lot of overhead in things like sessions and what not and unfortunately I don't have time to explain. Take a look at Connect middleware and how its used in Express. If you want to learn Node core, the best way is to start looking at some source code of projects like Express or Flatiron. Good luck!